# Qt Parsing a Custom File Format

Tags: c++, regex, qt, parsing

I have a bunch of custom scripts that have a file format similar, but not the same as JSON. I would like to take these files and spit their data into a QTreeWidget and display the raw code with some syntax highlighting. I do not need those tasks done, I just need a clean way or idea on how I can extract the information from these. Here is an example snippet from a script.

Example:

```
"People"
{
    "Person 1"
    {
        "age"       "34"
        "name"      "John"
        "gender"    "male"
        "skills"
        {
            "skill 1"   "Intelligent"
            "skill 2"   "Wise"
            "skill 3"   "Buff as a bear!"
        }
    }
    "Person 2"
    {
        "age"       "25"
        "name"      "Jamie"
        "gender"    "helicopter"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need a 'look forward variable? which will read the next token, while you processing the current one, so you can decide that the current one is a field of its parent or a name of a nested struct.

Comment: This format appears to be a context-free grammar; you'll need a stack to parse it. You might be able to tweak an existing JSON library to read the format.

Comment: @MrEricSir I mean All I have to do is add colons, commas, and a few brackets and boom it's JSON. Just such pain with RegExp's

Comment: @NicholasJohnson Forget using regular expressions in this case because you're not dealing with a regular grammar. It's far too complicated for a Stack Overflow comment, but the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) explains the distinction.

Comment: The simplest solution - quite trivial as the changes are just a few lines - is to copy Qt's Json implementation and tweak it to deal with your syntax. You got Qt's sources. Use them!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this to play a bit around with regex in C++11/14. But to be honest, this is not a fun problem and regex is probably the wrong tool for the job.

I came up with this code that converts your sample input into valid JSON:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;    
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
std::string test = R"(
"People"
{
    "Person 1"
    {
        "age"       "34"
        "name"      "John"
        "gender"    "male"
        "skills"
        {
            "skill 1"   "Intelligent"
            "skill 2"   "Wise"
            "skill 3"   "Buff as a bear!"
        }
    }
    "Person 2"
    {
        "age"       "25"
        "name"      "Jamie"
        "gender"    "helicopter"
    }
}
)";
    regex reg(R"(("[^"]+")\s+("[^"]+"))");
    test = std::regex_replace(test, reg, "$1:$2,");
    regex reg2(R"((?:\A|\n)\s*("[^"]+")\s*(\n|\Z))");
    test = std::regex_replace(test, reg2, "$1:");
    regex reg3(R"(}\s*("[^"]+"):\s*\{)");
    test = std::regex_replace(test, reg3, "},\n$1: {");
    regex reg4(R"(,\s*})");
    test = std::regex_replace(test, reg4, "}");
    cout << "{" << test << "}" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
{"People":{"Person 1":    {
        "age":"34",
        "name":"John",
        "gender":"male","skills":        {
            "skill 1":"Intelligent",
            "skill 2":"Wise",
            "skill 3":"Buff as a bear!"}
    },
"Person 2": {
        "age":"25",
        "name":"Jamie",
        "gender":"helicopter"}
}
}
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/FvyQfh)

However, your mileage may vary with different, more complex input.